# How can I extract variables with nonzero coefficients from an equation using a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I wish to grab the non-zero coefficients of a particular number arrangement. I have the set of numbers below and I wish to strictly extract with regex the non-zero coefficient (`x2`, `x3`, `x5`) from

```
x1 *0.000000+ x2 *-0.100000+ x3 *0.850000+ x4 *0.000000+ x5 *0.000056+ x6 *0.000000
```

I tried doing this

```
(\*[-+]?[0]*\.?[0]+)
```

but am not really sure as to declare that it shouldn't consider the `"*0.000000"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match x-digit *not* followed by space-star-zero-dot-zeroes-endOfWord:

```
x\d+(?! \*0\.0+\b)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/aRwiw9ypQB).

Comment: Works perfectly. Only that I needed to apply "\d+" if I need to consider range from x1 -> x11 .> x111 and so on. Very useful

Comment: @ifedee if this "answered your question", you should consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the fact that you have full-blown programming language at your disposal to simplify the regex to capture all coefficients, and then use [grep](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#grep-EXPR-LIST) to eliminate the zeros:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $eqn = "x1 *0.000000+ x2 *-0.100000+ x3 *0.850000+ x4 *0.000000+ x5 *0.000056+ x6 *0.000000 ";

my %eqn = ($eqn =~ /(x[0-9]+) \s [*] (-?[0-9.]+) [+]/gx);

print "$_\n" for grep $eqn{$_} != 0, keys %eqn;
```

Output (order will not be consistent unless you sort variable names):

```
x3 
x5 
x2
```

This might look like too much extra work, but having the equation parsed into a hash which maps variables to coefficients may actually save you work down the road depending on the exact nature of what you are doing. I am assuming you are doing some kind of model selection based on coefficient magnitudes.

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
x\d+(?!\s*\*0\.0*(?:[+\s]|$))
```

- `x\d+` gets `x` followed by one or more digits
- The zero width negative lookahead pattern `(?!\s*\*0\.0*(?:[+\s]|$))` ensures that the match is not followed by zero co-efficients

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X8frN8/3)

---

More robust, avoiding false positives in the match:

```
x\d+(?!\s*\*0\.0*(?:[+\s]|$))(?=\s*\*-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[+\s]|$))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X8frN8/4)

Comment: Many thanks. The robust version did exactly what I anticipated. Appreciate it.